# How to store current input values from a multipage form in cookie using ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a multipage form which I will use to capture data and save it into db. What I want to be able to accomplish is if the user decides they can't finish filling out the form they can close their browser and when they return to the site the form will repopulate with the values from their previous session. I know I will have to use a cookie to accomplish this. How can this be done using jquery ajax? I am using a joomla3 rsform component and unfortunately they don't provide this functionality.

Comment: Are you going to save it on field fill bases or complete form filled bases?

Comment: At the moment it is saving on complete form filled bases. I don't want to add it to the database until it is completely filled in.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have jquery plugin knowledge. You can use jquery cookie plugin.http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

And it is best to use `jquery serialize()`

Comment: I am using this jQuery('.rsform-button').click(function() {
        var data = $('#userForm').serialize();
        alert(data);
    }); to see if I can get the values of the form but I am getting this error: Unable to get value of the property 'serialize': object is null or undefined